# How can I convert from an object to a transform in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code used from a tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtY_R0g8L8E, but I seem to be getting this error:

Assets/LevelGenerator.cs(22,27): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Object' to` UnityEngine.Transform'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How do I fix this? Thanks

'''

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private Transform redLevelPart;
[SerializeField] private Transform yellowlevelPart;

void Awake() 
{
    Transform lastlevelTransform;
    lastlevelTransform = SpawnLevelPart(redLevelPart.Find ("EndPosition").position);
    lastlevelTransform = SpawnLevelPart(lastlevelTransform.Find ("EndPosition").position);
    lastlevelTransform = SpawnLevelPart(lastlevelTransform.Find ("EndPosition").position);
    lastlevelTransform = SpawnLevelPart(lastlevelTransform.Find ("EndPosition").position);
    lastlevelTransform = SpawnLevelPart(lastlevelTransform.Find ("EndPosition").position);
}
// Update is called once per frame
private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Vector3 spawnpoint)
{
    Transform levelTransform =  Instantiate(yellowlevelPart, spawnpoint, Quaternion.identity);
    return levelTransform;
}
```

}

'''

Comment: Instantiate returns a GameObject. You must reference its transform member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
Transform levelTransform =  Instantiate(yellowlevelPart, spawnpoint, Quaternion.identity);
```

The error message is telling you that you're trying to assign an Object type to a variable of the Transform type.  That's because the Instantiate() method returns a GameObject (not a Transform) but you're assigning it to `levelTransform` which has the Transform type.

You can solve that by referencing the transform component of the GameObject that `Instantiate()` returns. For example:

```
private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Vector3 spawnpoint)
{
    GameObject levelObject =  Instantiate(yellowlevelPart, spawnpoint, Quaternion.identity);
    Transform levelTransform = levelObject.transform;
    return levelTransform;
}
```

Or more tersely:

```
private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Vector3 spawnpoint)
{
    return Instantiate(yellowlevelPart, spawnpoint, Quaternion.identity).transform;
}
```